# Does a longer stator equal more torque in a BLDC setup?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, torque, stator

I'm interested in making something like this:
http://www.vivax-assist.com/en/produkte/vivax-assist-4-0/vivax-assist_4-0.php

Because it looks awesome, but for the price i could buy a motorcycle and the needed driver's license(!).

I think i remember reading somewhere that a longer stator = more torque, while more windings = more speed. I could not find anything to back up this theory though, so now I'm asking here.

So, smart people of this forum, does this theory hold up? Or is it just something I've been telling myself and mistakenly taken as something i read once?

Cheers

Comment: For same power; P=const: Longer stator = smaller diameter = less torque/higher speed; Short staror = larger dimeter = more torque/low speed;

Comment: Power = torque x speed. (In SI units to about 2% Watts = kg.m x RPM) . For a given power torque is inversely proportional to speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes an increase in active length (stator and rotor) will produce "more torque" for a given operating point.

The size of a motor is determined by the torque it has to deliver. For similar motors with similar cooling systems the motor torque is proportional to the volume of the rotor and hence the overall motor volume.

However... an increase in length will increase the rotor's inertia which may or may not be tolerable for the system.

Increasing the number of turns will also increase the torque production as the number of amp-turns increases.

Both of these will increase the motor's torque constant Kt, but also the motor voltage constant Ke. This will potentially limit the maximum speed with respect to the inverters voltage source.

Answer (score 0):

When you say a longer stator, I assume you mean the rotor will get longer as well.

Torque in a motor is proportional to the air gap flux, the number of conductors in the slots and the current in those conductors.  Assuming the air gap flux density stays the same, then a longer stator will mean more air gap flux and your torque will increase.  At the same time, a longer stator will slightly increase the total length of your wire, so your resistance will increase and that will cause the torque to drop slightly.  But because your motor is longer, it also has the ability to dissipate more heat which increases your rated torque.  The overall effect is a longer motor will increase torque, assuming everything else about the motor stays the same.

If you increase the number of turns in your coils, it will also increase the torque since, as I mentioned above, torque is proportional to the number of conductors.

No-load speed is actually inversely proportional to the air gap flux and the number of conductors, so both increasing the length of the motor and increasing the number of turns in the coils will slow the motor down.

Comment: "If you increase the number of turns in your coils, it will also increase the torque " but, of course, for the same volume the wire size will have to go down proportionately, so heat dissipation rises. Alas, you just can't win.